# Is 'negative result', standard terminology?

Tags: probability, terminology

In studying the statistical classification (or discrimination) problem, I encountered a central result that states that there cannot exist a classification rule that converges towards Bayes classifier, with a specified rate of convergence. In, [A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition](https://www.szit.bme.hu/%7Egyorfi/pbook.pdf) (Devroye et al.) they call such impossibility results, `negative results'.

I am wondering whether this terminology is standard? Are theorems that proof the impossibility of a particular situation referred to as 'negative' more generally, or is this terminology specific to these authors?

Comment: The impossibility to solve polynomial equations by radicals in general if the degree is higher than $4$ is sometimes called a "negative result". So, I think this terminology is common.

Comment: "Negative result" is a common phrase across science and related fields, and the meaning being used here is essentially the same as the usual one.

Comment: To clarify, no one would say "that's a negative theorem" because "negative result" is basically a set phrase in English.

Comment: @MarkS. Thanks for posting your comment. In my understanding, a negative result, more generally in science, is a result that disproves the proposed hypotheses (fails to give sufficient evidence in favor of it). So in my example, you say "essentially the same", due to an implied hypothesis that there do exists classification rules with a specified rate. This is a positive (noun) hypothesis in this particular subject.